# Webkit Speech Recognition on Audio File

Tags: javascript, audio, webkitspeechrecognition

I am working on a small web app and have successfully used the webkit speech recognition in Chrome, to output the speech to text using the microphone, using example 4 from here:
https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html#examples-recognition

I was wondering if anyone knew if it is possible to use an audio file as the audio input, instead of using the microphone?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! TIA

Comment: the API does not, but you may for a single device, be able to setup the audio input/output so that audio output is routed to the line in or mic, which would let you get stuff done for you.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. This is my first time developing with the webkit speech recognition, so I will look into the devices.

Comment: Hi @Ronnyvdb , have you had any luck with that?